# Javascript: function to describe array is skipping most of the actual function and returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, math, return

I am trying to write a single javascript function that will take in a list of numbers as arguments and will output the number of odd number, number of negative numbers, will average the numbers, and will output the median. I believe I basically have completed all of the code, but am either confusing my syntax or am incorrectly returning.

Code:

```
 var arrayAnalyze = function(numbers){
    var oddNum = []; //Array of odd numbers
    var negNum = []; //Array of negative numbers
    var numSum = 0; // Sum of all numbers
    var avgNum = 0; //Average of all numbers
    var midNum = []; //Median number

    //Return odd numbers to oddNum array
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        if (numbers[i] % 2 !== 0){
            oddNum.push(numbers[i]);
        }
    }

    //Return negative numbers to negNum array
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        if (Math.abs(numbers[i]) + numbers[i] === 0){
            negNum.push(numbers[i]);
        }
    }

    //Return sum of all numbers to numSum variable
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        numSum += i;
    }

    //Return average of numbers to avgNum variable
    avgNum = numSum / numbers.length;

    //Return median of numbers to midNum array
    numbers.sort(function(a,b){return a - b;});
    var evenSplit = Math.floor(numbers.length / 2);
    if(numbers.length % 2){
        midNum = numbers[evenSplit];
    }else{
        midNum = (numbers[evenSplit - 1] + numbers[evenSplit]) / 2.0;                       }
    midNum.push();

    return "Odds: " + oddNum.length, "Negatives: " + negNum.length, "Average: " + avgNum.toFixed(2), "Median: " + midNum[0];
};

console.log(arrayAnalyze(7, -3, 0, 12, 44, -5, 3));
```

Output:
`TypeError: numbers.sort is not a function`

Comment: You might want to get familiar with [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)? "When a return statement is called in a function, the execution of this function is stopped." That's that, looking at the first `if..else`, you're returning either a number or `false`, the rest of the function will never be executed.

Comment: Is that because you see a mistake in my use or `return`, or because of my obvious lack of confidence with it?

Comment: Basically, remove all `return` except the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of errors that you'd want to correct - comments inline

```
var arrayAnalyze = function (numbers) {
    var oddNum = []; //Array of odd numbers
    var negNum = []; //Array of negative numbers
    var numSum = 0; // Sum of all numbers
    var avgNum = 0; //Average of all numbers
    var midNum = []; //Median number

    //Return odd numbers to oddNum array
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        // always check the element at index, i is just the index
        if (numbers[i] % 2 !== 0) {
            // return exits the currently running function! (not the block)
            oddNum.push(numbers[i]);
        } 
    }

    //Return negative numbers to negNum array
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        // exclude 0 here
        if (Math.abs(numbers[i]) + numbers[i] === 0 && numbers[i]) {
            negNum.push(numbers[i]);
        } 
    }

    //Return sum of all numbers to numSum variable
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numSum += numbers[i];
    }

    //Return average of numbers to avgNum variable
    avgNum = numSum / numbers.length;

    //Return median of numbers to midNum array
    // if you are using a function you need to invoke it to get it's value
    midNum.push((function median(numbers) {
        // note that this will actually sort the elements of the array you pass in in-place
        numbers.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
        var evenSplit = Math.floor(numbers.length / 2);
        if (numbers.length % 2) {
            return numbers[evenSplit];
        } else {
            return (numbers[evenSplit - 1] + numbers[evenSplit]) / 2.0;
        }
    })(numbers));
    // use + to concatenate the strings, otherwise it just becomes a bunch of comma separated expressions
    return "Odds: " + oddNum.length + ",Negatives: " + negNum.length + ",Average: " + avgNum.toFixed(2) + ",Median: " + midNum[0];
};

// an array is passed in using square brackets
console.log(arrayAnalyze([7, -3, 0, 12, 44, -5, 3]));
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a fundamental misunderstand of what `return` does. MDN has a page on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Examples

`return` interrupts code execution, exits the innermost function and returns a value to the caller.

```
function myFunction() {
    return "foo";
    alert("This will never be reached!");
}
alert(myFunction()) // Equivalent to alert("foo").
```

For example, in your code:

```
//Return odd numbers to oddNum array
for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    if (i % 2 !== 0){
        return oddNum.push(i); // <- code execution will stop here
    }else{
        return false; // <- or here, whichever is reached first.
    }
}
```

Which means your loop will never execute for more than one iteration. So when you call

```
console.log(arrayAnalyze(7, -3, 0, 12, 44, -5, 3));
```

The first value is odd, so the function will stop at `return oddNum.push(i);`. And since `oddNum.push(i)` itself returns nothing (`undefined`), `arrayAnalyze` will return `undefined` too, and the log will be equivalent to

```
console.log(undefined);
```

Which is what you are seeing.

In this case the returns are completely unnecessary and the loop should read:

```
//Return odd numbers to oddNum array
for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    if (i % 2 !== 0){
        oddNum.push(i); // <- now code execution is not interrupted!
    }
}
```

And so on, through the rest of the code.

Also, at the end you declare a function called `median`:

```
//Return median of numbers to midNum array
function median(numbers) {
    [...]
}
```

But you never invoke it (calling `median(someValue)`), which means the code inside it will never be executed either. I haven't checked the code for mathematical correctness, but I believe you should just remove the `median` declaration and leave its body inside the main `arrayAnalyze` function.

Answer (score 1):

when a function hits a `return` statement it will exit out meaning the any code beneath the `return` will not get executed.

Answer (score 1):

In your odd number sorter you use the %/Modulus on the counter/index rather than numbers[i] to use it on each element of the numbers array parameter. This also needs fixed when you push to the appropriate results array. I have spotted this same concept being done multiple times throughout the function so I would go back and correct that as it would break a couple things.

Also to give you a tip in the right direction in terms of learning return like other users are saying, let's take a look at this part of your code:

```
for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        return numSum += i;
    }
```

You do not need to return numSum as your are returning its value later at the end. Just updated the variable you initialized at the beginning by doing the following (also updated in regards to my suggestion above):

```
for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        numSum += numbers[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cleary are pretty confused about how the `return` keyword works; I suggest you to check out some documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp).

As an example, you need to change that piece of code

```
if (numbers % 2 !== 0){
    return oddNum.push(numbers);
}else{
    return false;
}
```

into

```
if (numbers % 2 !== 0){
    oddNum.push(numbers);
}
```

All the others `if` structures have the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this :

```
var arrayAnalyze = function (numbers) {
var oddNum = []; //Array of odd numbers
var negNum = []; //Array of negative numbers
var numSum = 0; // Sum of all numbers
var avgNum = 0; //Average of all numbers
var midNum = []; //Median number

//Return odd numbers to oddNum array
for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 !== 0) {
        oddNum.push(numbers[i]);
    } 
}

//Return negative numbers to negNum array
for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (Math.abs(numbers[i]) + numbers[i] === 0) {
        negNum.push(numbers[i]);
    } 
}

//Return sum of all numbers to numSum variable
for (numbers[i] = 0; numbers[i] < numbers.length; numbers[i]++) {
    numSum += numbers[i];
}

//Return average of numbers to avgNum variable
avgNum = numSum / numbers.length;

//Return median of numbers to midNum array
var newArrayOfNumber = numbers;
newArrayOfNumber.sort();

var evenSplit = Math.floor(newArrayOfNumber.length / 2);
if (newArrayOfNumber.length % 2) {
    midNum = newArrayOfNumber[evenSplit];
} else {
    midNum = (newArrayOfNumber[evenSplit - 1] + newArrayOfNumber[evenSplit]) / 2.0;
}

return "Odds: " + oddNum.length + ", Negatives: " + negNum.length +", Average: " + avgNum.toFixed(2) +", Median: " + midNum;
```

};

When you call the function you should pass a array to it, so just add [] to your numbers like this : arrayAnalyze([7, -3, 0, 12, 44, -5, 3])

it should return :"Odds: 3, Negatives: 3, Average: 3.50, Median: 7.5"

When you want to add some number to a array in a for block or a if block, dont use return, just do the operation and if you want to break the for loop, use the line :
Break;

and when you want to access the number in your for loop, you should call the array and not only the i, like this : number[i]

espering that it help you

sorry for my mistakes in writting in english